# Linux doesn't close TCP connection after change a Wi-Fi network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, tcp, cloud

There is some TCP connection between some device behind NAT (Wi-Fi router) and server, located in Google Cloud, both under Ubuntu 16.04. When I changed a Wi-Fi network, this device keeps this connection in "ESTABLISHED" state, though the server drops it.

Before change:

- Server

  ```
  root@server:~# netstat -natp | grep 8080
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1810/crossbar-worker
  tcp        0      0 10.142.X.X:8080         73.XXX.XXX.XXX:49514    ESTABLISHED 1810/crossbar-worker
  ```
- Client

  ```
  root@client:~# netstat -natp | grep 8080
  tcp        0      0 192.168.X.X:49514     35.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080        ESTABLISHED 9089/crossbar-worker
  ```

After change:

- Server

  ```
  root@server:~# netstat -natp | grep 8080
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1810/crossbar-worker
  ```
- Client

  ```
  root@client:~# netstat -natp | grep 8080
  tcp        0      0 192.168.X.X:49514     35.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080       ESTABLISHED 9089/crossbar-worker
  ```

Why doesn't my device drop that TCP connection?

Additional info:
TCP keepalive

- Server

  ```
  root@server:~# grep -H '' /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive*
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl:75
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes:9
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time:7200
  ```
- Client

  ```
  root@client:~# grep -H '' /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive*
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl:75
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes:9
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time:7200
  ```

Comment: Please include the output of `grep -H '' /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive*` from both systems ([edit] this information into the question).

Comment: As long as neither the client nor the server send a `FIN` and the timeout (see @KamilMaciorowski 's comment) isn't exceeded the connection stays *established* ...